# Transparent RewriteRule does not apply to folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a RewriteRule in a .htaccess file to transparently redirect all requests to a specific domain to a subfolder.

```
# mydomain.ch -> mydomain.ch/domainfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.ch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domainfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works perfectly for accessing files.

E.g. when a visitor tries to access https://mydomain.ch/index.html it shows the index.html file from the domainfolder. The visitor never sees the domainfolder part in the url in the addressbar

When I try to access a folder on this webpage (e.g. pictures), instead of showing https://mydomain.ch/pictures/ it converts the request to https://mydomain.ch/domainfolder/pictures/

The domainfolder should never be visible to the visitor. How can I modify the RewriteRule to work transparently for both, files and folders?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your rules in .htaccess line "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" to exclude directories

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.ch
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !domainfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domainfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when I try to access the subfolder with a trailing /, like https://mydomain.ch/pictures/ but when I omit the slash like https://mydomain/pictures it's still rewritten to https://mydomain/domainfolder/pictures